# php mysql update all fields

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for asking a trivial question. I want to translate some of the fields of my database which has one million rows. So what I want to do is 
to read field 1 and perform the translate function and write it to field 3 and respectively field 2 needs to be written into field 4.

**initial table**
field id|field 1 |field 2   |field 3|field 4|
 1      | apple  | pear     | empty |empty   |
 2      | banana | pineapple | empty |empty   |

**end result table translate(apple) - yabloko**

field id|field 1 |field 2     |field 3|field 4|
 1      | apple  | pear       | yablogo |grusha   |
 2      | banana | pineapple  | banan |ananas   |

I already have the translate function, the question is how to perform 
this on all one million rows. How to construct the loop through it correctly? (surely there are some IDs missing, as some of the data was removed).

thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: Quite the monumental task. Which API are you using?

Comment: How to construct a loop (for what would otherwise be) a straightforward update so the entire "one million rows"+ can be processed RBAR (row by agonizing row) in a loop... no, I wouldn't categorize that as a trivial question. (I'd much prefer to answer a different question, about how to load a new translation table and perform the update operation on the entire set, in one fell swoop.) (+ I just so want to use my best Dr.Evil impersonation, with a pinky finger to the corner of my mouth, and say  "One million rows".)

Comment: *...pretty much* - @spencer7593

Comment: hmm good point, row by row should do the work too, as I need to do it only once, all the future data will be translated automatically.

Comment: Gys whould this work? 

 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DB_Table);
 
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 
   $id=$result['field_id'];
   $field1=$result['field1'];
   
   $insert1 = translate($field1);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO DB_Table (field3) 
           VALUES ('$insert1')");
}

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "construct a loop" and process row by row, the normative pattern would be to perform the operation in a single statement.

I'd populate a translation table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_translation
( old_word VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, new_word VARCHAR(100)
) Engine=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO my_translation (old_word, new_word) VALUES
 ('apple'    ,'yablogo')
,('pear'     ,'grush')
,('banana'   ,'banan')
,('pineapple','ananas);
```

Then do an update. The tricky part is leaving `field_3` and `field_4` unmodified if there's no match.

```
UPDATE my_table t
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_translation c3
       ON c3.old_word = t.field_1
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_translation c4
       ON c4.old_word = t.field_2
   SET t.field_3 = IF(c3.old_word IS NULL,t.field_3,c3.new_word)
     , t.field_4 = IF(c4.old_word IS NULL,t.field_4,c4.new_word)
```

NOTE: If this is a one-time operation, I might consider doing this as an INSERT into a new table, and then swapping the table names and changing foreign key references, to put the new table in place of the old table.

Comment: how about this? would it work?

 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DB_Table);
 
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 
   $id=$result['field_id'];
   $field1=$result['field1'];
   
   $insert1 = translate($field1);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO DB_Table (field3) 
           VALUES ('$insert1')");
}

Comment: @migrant: ACCKKK!!! It's 2015. Why are we *still* using the deprecated `mysql` interface for new development, when there are two suitable interfaces available: `mysqli` and `PDO`. And why are we *still* writing code that is vulnerable to SQL Injection? And no, that wouldn't work. You'd need an UPDATE statement with a predicate (WHERE clause) that identifies the row to be updated by a unique key... `WHERE t.field_id = 42`